# Refresh a ListView implemented using Lazy Load and JSON

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, android-listview

I have implement Fedor's Lazy Load code to implement a subset of my application. I am pulling data using the facebook sdk and showing a newsfeed post with its comments, like count, etc in an activity. There is also a comment box using which, you can post a comment to the newsfeed post. This function works just fine. What I want to do however is, after a user has posted his comment to the thread, the list should refresh and also display the comment he just posted. I have tried calling the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the onClick method right after posting the comment. The listview never refreshes though.

Correct me if I am wrong here, but my best guess is, the arraylist I have used to hold the data is not refreshing. Here are the (what I think) relevant parts of the code. Please let me know if more is needed.

The onCreate method: initialize the ArrayLists and pull data using JSONObject and JSONArray

```
arrayUserID = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayProfilePic = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayFromName = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayMessage = new ArrayList<String>();


try {

    JOFeedDetails = new JSONObject(apiResponse);
    JAFeedDetails = JOFeedDetails.getJSONArray("data");


    for (int i = 0; i < JAFeedDetails.length(); i++) {
        json_data = JAFeedDetails.getJSONObject(i);

        // GET THE POST'S FROM USER NAME AND ID
        JSONObject joFromName = new JSONObject();
        joFromName = json_data.optJSONObject("from");

        if (joFromName.has("id"))   {
            String getCommentersID = joFromName.getString("id");
            arrayUserID.add(getCommentersID);
            String fromProfilePic = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ getCommentersID +"/picture?type=square" + "&access_token=" + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken();;
            arrayProfilePic.add(fromProfilePic);
        } else {
            String getCommentersID = "";
            arrayUserID.add(getCommentersID);
        }

        if (joFromName.has("name")) {
            String getCommentersName = joFromName.getString("name");
            arrayFromName.add(getCommentersName);
        } else {
            String getCommentersName = "";
            arrayFromName.add(getCommentersName);
        }

        if (json_data.has("message"))   {
            String getMessage = json_data.getString("message");
            arrayMessage.add(getMessage);
        } else {
            String getMessage = "";
            arrayMessage.add(getMessage);
        }

        // GET THE POST'S TIME STAMP
        if(json_data.has("created_time"))   {

            String dateStr = json_data.optString("created_time");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = getDateFormat();
            ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
            long then = formatter.parse(dateStr, pos).getTime();
            long now = new Date().getTime();

            long seconds = (now - then)/1000;
            long minutes = seconds/60;
            long hours = minutes/60;
            long days = hours/24;

            String friendly = null;
            long num = 0;
            if (days > 0) {
                num = days;
                friendly = days + " day";
            } else if (hours > 0) {
                num = hours;
                friendly = hours + " hour";
            } else if (minutes > 0) {
                num = minutes;
                friendly = minutes + " minute";
            } else {
                num = seconds;
                friendly = seconds + " second";
            }
            if (num > 1) {
                friendly += "s";
            }
            String postTimeStamp = friendly.toUpperCase() + " AGO";
            arrayTimeStamp.add(postTimeStamp);
        } else {
            String postTimeStamp = "";
            arrayTimeStamp.add(postTimeStamp);
        }

        if (json_data.has("likes")) {
            String getCommentLikes = json_data.getString("likes");
            arrayCountLikes.add(getCommentLikes);
        } else {
            String getCommentLikes = "0";
            arrayCountLikes.add(getCommentLikes);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
}

stringUserID = new String[arrayUserID.size()];
stringUserID = arrayUserID.toArray(stringUserID);

stringProfilePics = new String[arrayProfilePic.size()];
stringProfilePics = arrayProfilePic.toArray(stringProfilePics);

stringFromName = new String[arrayFromName.size()];
stringFromName = arrayFromName.toArray(stringFromName);

stringMessage = new String[arrayMessage.size()];
stringMessage = arrayMessage.toArray(stringMessage);

stringTimeStamp = new String[arrayTimeStamp.size()];
stringTimeStamp = arrayTimeStamp.toArray(stringTimeStamp);

stringCountLikes = new String[arrayCountLikes.size()];
stringCountLikes = arrayCountLikes.toArray(stringCountLikes);

getNewsfeedDetailsHeader();

adapter = new NewsFeedDetailsAdapter(this, stringUserID, stringFromName, stringProfilePics, 
        stringMessage, stringTimeStamp, stringCountLikes);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the onClick event from where the comment is posted:

```
public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", txtCommentBox.getText().toString());
                parameters.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
                parameters.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));

                Utility.mFacebook.request(fetchedThreadID + "/comments", parameters, "POST");

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtCommentBox.getWindowToken(), 0);
                txtCommentBox.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
```

I really appreciate your patience going through this long post. But I really think it might be helpful to understand the flow. I hope someone here can help get me through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem once where my ArrayLists were not updating.

try calling .clear() on your Arraylist before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()   this worked for me.  Good luck!